# How to properly redirect a request from QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo?

Tags: python, qt, qt5, qwebengine

I'm writing a little plugin for Falkon, whose task is very simple: redirect requests from youtube.com to piped.video. It does it, but only if there is nothing in the URL except the domain (i.e. just "youtube.com"), and if there is, youtube page appears with an internet connection error. Here is the code:

```py
import Falkon
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineCore
from urllib.parse import urlparse


class YoutubeToPiped(Falkon.PluginInterface, QtCore.QObject):
    def init(self, state, settingsPath):
        self.interceptor = YoutubeToPipedInterceptor()

        Falkon.MainApplication.instance().networkManager().installUrlInterceptor(self.interceptor)

    def unload(self):
        pass

    def testPlugin(self):
        return True


class YoutubeToPipedInterceptor(Falkon.UrlInterceptor):
    def interceptRequest(self, info: QtWebEngineCore.QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo):
        requestUrl = urlparse(info.requestUrl().toString())
        if "youtube.com" in requestUrl.netloc or "youtu.be" in requestUrl.netloc:
            info.redirect(QtCore.QUrl(f"https://piped.video{requestUrl.path}?{requestUrl.query}"))


Falkon.registerPlugin(YoutubeToPiped())
```

What am I doing wrong and/or is there any other method to solve this problem?